# How do I change the text color of a button for different states in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, expression-blend, blend

I'm still learning Blend, so please bear with me.  I have a toggle button in a WPF project and I need to change the text color for different states such as mouseover and checked.  However, when I'm editing the template and I select the contentPresenter, the only brush is OpacityMask and it is not affected by any brush color changes.

I can of course change the text color by editing the style, but this is not useful as it is within  the states I'm interesting in editing.

Basically, I simply want the text of the button to change on mouseover, hover, etc, this seems a reasonable thing to do, but the OpacityMask Brush of the ContentPresenter cannot be edited.

Someone mentioned to change the ContentPresenter into a ContentControl.  This does work, but I now cannot edit the text for an instance of the button.  Do I have to link the ContentControl to something?

Many thanks for any help.  I'm stuck right here for a few hours and I've been searching everywhere for the answer, to no avail

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do it in style.

Comment: Hi Viktor, many thanks for your answer, however I want to avoid triggers if at all possible as I was looking for something more flexible (i.e. set it and forget it) as I'm doing a lot with the text properties and wouldn't want to be setting triggers every time.  Viv's answer was the one I followed, the update part though, as that allowed me to work with text as if it was simply a normal textbox.  many thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what your looking for without having to use a `ContentControl` and by just using the `VisualStateManager`

> I can of course change the text color by editing the style, but this is not useful as it is within the states I'm interesting in editing.

So say for example the state to apply a new `Foreground` color to the text of your `Button` is `MouseOver`,

- Firstly Blend does not create a `Brush` resource for `Button.MouseOver.Foreground` when editing a `Button` template.

so let's create one. (Just add the following line along with the other brush resources)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Foreground" Color="Tomato" />
```

- Now we can apply a `Storyboard` to the `TextElement.Foreground` of the `contentPresenter`.

so your VSM will look like:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
      <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Foreground}, Path=Color}" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

and that's it.

Do note what we're doing here would be fine **only** when the `Content` of the `Button` is just text, but since that's what your usage is as mentioned in your question, you should be fine.

**Sidenote:**

You can do the exact same thing by just switching the `ContentPresenter` to a `TextBlock` in the `ControlTemplate`.

If you need the `Foreground` to be available for any `Content` of the `Button`, then yeh just switch the `ContentPresenter` to a `ContentControl` and you can still your VSM Storyboard's in a very similar way.

**Update**:

To switch the `ContentPresenter` to a `ContentControl`, in your `ControlTemplate` just switch the actual element with the new one.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  ...
  <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
  ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

to:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  ...
  <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
  ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

you would have to update their properties accordingly like for eg `ContentControl` does not support `RecognizesAccessKeys` and it also needs `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` set on it to actually show the content. With a `ContentPresenter` the `Content` property is set implicitly.

Comment: Hi Viv, many thanks for this, i'm trying it out now.  Just one thing - is it possible to just change the ContentPresenter into a ContentControl, how would I do that?  Or, if I add a ContentControl or textblock into the control template, how do I make it so that the textblock now becomes the part that is the Content of the button?

Comment: @JohnRooney check my update at the bottom of the post. Also just search for other examples of custom `Button.Style`'s and you'll find some decent examples about these. If I add every bit I can think of, We'll be here for hours. go with google search terms like `wpf button ContentPresenter vs ContentControl`, `wpf button Apply dynamic color to child controls`, `wpf why use templateBinding` and you should have a ton to read about :)

Comment: many many thanks viv, I followed your last update,  I needed to do more things to the text so it was a better option to just outright swap it for a contentcontrol.  thank you, you saved me a lot of headache, I couldn't find the solution anywhere

Comment: viv, would you mind helping me out on my new question re: creating a custom title bar? thanks

Comment: Viv, I'm coming across quite a few problems and would also like to learn a lot more about Blend and WPF in general.  Would you be willing to do a half-day / full-day paid consultancy with me?

Comment: @JohnRooney depends on what it is that you're trying to solve/learn. You can ping me on viv.rajkumar@maidsafe.net with some info on what you're trying to learn cos in most cases, you could just be pointed to the resources that are available out there and you wouldn't need to pay someone for that. It's what this site is for :) (helping others).

Answer (score 1):

Foreground property is present in Style. So you can edit Style and there you can set `Foreground`. It could be something like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Or if you want to change it in `ControlTemplate` then you can do it like this.

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenterName" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

So in expression blend you do it like this

1. Locate your Style in the **Resources** panel, and then click the **Edit** resource button next to the resource. Or right-click and choose **Edit**.
2. Add trigger in **Triggers** panel.
3. Go to **Properties** panel and change Foreground property.